# Jest mockResolvedValue does not work with arrays in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs

We have a puzzling issue here. Why does Jest mockResolvedValue not work on mocking a resolved value of array. Where the same value works in mockImplementation.

```
export interface Car {
    name: string;
    key: string;
    count?: number;
}

async getCars(): Promise<Car[]> {
    const results = await someLongCall()   // async call
    const c: Car[] = [...results];  // return is of type Car[]
    return c;
}
```

in the tests we have

```
const c: Car[] = [
 {name: 'aaaaa', key: 'aaaaa', count: 10}, 
 {name: 'bbbbb', key: 'bbbbb', count: 20}
 ];

// this fails
_wSpy1 = jest.spyOn(CarSevice.prototype, 'getCars')
      .mockResolvedValue(c);  <= Error here ?


// but this works
_wSpy1 = jest.spyOn(CarSevice.prototype, 'getCars')
   .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(c));
```

The error we get is:

```
// We get this error:

Error: Argument of type 'Car[]' is not assignable to parameter of 
type 'Promise<Car[]> | PromiseLike<Promise<Car[]>>'.
Property 'then' is missing in type 'Car[]' but required in type
'PromiseLike<Promise<Car[]>>'. 
[2345] lib.es5.d.ts(1383, 5): 'then' is declared here.
```

the signature of mockResolvedValue is below. Can't value not be on type array?

```
/**
 * Simple sugar function for: `jest.fn().mockImplementation(() =>
    Promise.resolve(value));`
 */
mockResolvedValue(value: T | PromiseLike<T>): Mock<Promise<T>, Y>;
```

Comment: Do you also have a problem with non-array values?

Comment: `mockResovledValue(Promise.resolve(c));` will temporary solve the problem for me.

Comment: It seems to be a problem in the jest type definition file. In definition `mockResolvedValue(value: T | PromiseLike<T>): Mock<Promise<T>, Y>;`, type `T` is the return value type of the function, which is in your case `Promise<Car[]>` instead of `Car[]`, so the value type should be `Promise<Car[]>`. But the problem is, according to the Jest documentation, the parameter here should be typed `Car[]`, that probably has caused the confusion.

To create an issue in the DefinitelyTyped repo seems to be a better idea than in SO, since the situation probably won't last long.

Comment: cool. just making sure I was not doing something wrong. I filed a bug jest team. https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7952